# csv reading in pig, csv file contains quoted comma

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

So my data looks something like this

```
asdf, asdf, "adsf,qwef", asdf
```

When i read that data in pig using

```
PigStorage(',')
```

It stores the "adsf,qwef" as a two data, and stores it like

```
{ "adsf } { qwef" }
```

I want quotes to be treated as single data.

What should I do?

**Im trying to write a pigscript to do this.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the CSVLoader:

```
data = LOAD 'my.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage() 
    AS (...);
```

Where the ... is the identifiers.

NOTE: You'll have to register the Piggybank first. Details here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank

Comment: is this a separate function besides the pig?

Comment: because it gives me error **2013-07-23 10:06:17,190 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]**

Comment: This has been updated/renamed to 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader()'