# Apache Pig - How to read data from CSV file

Tags: apache-pig

Apache Pig - How to read data from CSV file with data optionally enclosed within double quotes?

Sample data is provided below:

```
"Traditional",0.03,"Department, of Housing and Urban Development (HUD)",0.01
```

Expected Output :

```
Traditional  0.03  Department, of Housing and Urban Development (HUD)  0.01
```

In the above example we have 4 columns. 2 are enclosed in double quotes and 2 are not and are of floating data type. Moreover there is 3rd column which is having a comma in the data itself.

Please help me with some Pig related API's (sample code) which would help to split the data correctly and process them using positional notation say $0, $1, $2, $3.

I have explored `CSVExcelStorage` and `CSVLoader` from `PiggyBank`, but I am not able to split properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [csv reading in pig, csv file contains quoted comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816078/csv-reading-in-pig-csv-file-contains-quoted-comma)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = LOAD 'filename.csv' USING PigStorage (',') AS (fieldname:chararray, fieldname2:float);

DUMP a;
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it explained what the code it provided does.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 – Using CSVLoader or CSVExcelStorage

```
 REGISTER piggybank.jar;
 DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();

 a = load 'data' USING CSVLoader(',') AS (field1:chararray,field2:double,
                                          field3:chararray,field4:chararray);

 b = FOREACH a GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3;

 DUMP b;
```

Option 2 – TextLoader + STRSPLIT + REPLACE

```
 A = LOAD '/path/to/files/' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);

 B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'"','');

 C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, ','));

 DUMP C;
```