# Pig — how to load a CSV file having fields enclosed within double quotes and separated by comma

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a .csv file and data in it is similar as below:

```
001, 4567, 7012, “x,y,z”, abc, pqr, 56
002, 3456, 5457, “t,f,q”, str, whg, 78
003, 6782, 4562, “h,s,w”, uij, edc, 39
004, 2348, 2673, “k,g,r”, plg, esa, 57
```

When I load this data into PIG using `PigStorage(‘,’)`, the data within the double quotes is also considered as separate fields, because of the ‘,’ in the data.

My requirement is to consider the data within quotes as a single field and others as separate fields based on the comma delimited.
Can someone please suggest how can I achieve this.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: have you tried [CSVLoader or CSVExcelStorage](http://www.crackinghadoop.com/hadoop-pig-loading-files-with-quotes-and-comma-delimiters/)?

Answer (score 0):

check out these :
Download the piggybank jar first.

> [csv reading in pig, csv file contains quoted comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816078/csv-reading-in-pig-csv-file-contains-quoted-comma)
>   http://help.mortardata.com/integrations/amazon_s3/csv